# Long-polling in Laravel chat: Why is the div not updating itself?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel-4, long-polling

I'm trying to build a laravel chat app with long-polling (I know there's [nodejs/redis](http://www.volkomenjuist.nl/blog/2013/10/20/laravel-4-and-nodejsredis-pubsub-realtime-notifications/) but there's a [problem](https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-129095.html)) and therefore I have been trying to implement this [example](https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling/blob/master/server/server.php) into Laravel and MySQL.

However, the AJAX GET status request is **always stuck** at `pending...`. I figured this might be the cause that it is not updating
the div where I display my new newly inputted value from an AJAX POST request on the same page. Currently, the div only updates itself on refresh.

Here are my codes :

**View**

```
function getMsg(timestamp){
    var queryString = {"timestamp":timestamp};
    $.get(
        "create",
        queryString,
        function(data){
            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(obj.timestamp);
            $('#response').append('<p>'+obj.body+'</p>');
            getMsg(obj.timestamp);
        }
    ).fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });
}
getMsg();
```

**Controller**

```
public function create()
{
    $Msg = new Chatting;
    if(Request::ajax()){
        set_time_limit(0);
        session_write_close();
        while(true){

            $last_ajax_call = isset($_GET['timestamp'])?(int)$_GET['timestamp']:null;

            clearstatcache();
            $last_timestamp = $Msg->select(array('created_at'))->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
            $last_change = json_decode($last_timestamp);
            if($last_ajax_call == null || $last_change->created_at > $last_ajax_call){
                $result = array(
                    'body'=> $Msg->select('body','created_at')->where('created_at','=',$last_change->created_at)->first()->body,
                    'timestamp'=> $last_change->created_at
                );
                $json = json_encode($result);
                echo $json;
                break;
            }else{
                sleep(1);
            }
        }

    }else{
        $msgdata = $Msg->select(array('created_at','body'))->orderBy('created_at','asc')->get();
        return View::make('brightcms.Chatting.Chatting',compact('msgdata'));
    }
}
```

**GET Request Header**

```
Request URL:http://localhost/msgsys/public/cms/Chatting/create?timestamp=2014-06-09+06%3A49%3A11
Request Headers CAUTION: Provisional headers are shown.
Accept:*/*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost/msgsys/public/cms/Chatting/create
Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
timestamp:2014-06-09 06:49:11
```

Btw, bonus points for best ways to :

1. Improve the code so that it makes the most out of Laravel 4's functions and ways of doing stuff.
2. Run NodeJS on dreamhost/shared server without any restriction. Currently, there's this [problem](https://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-129095.html).

So yeah, how do I fix my code so that when I input a new value, the app will update a div to display the newly inputted value like a real-time app?

I'm still quite new in Laravel and would appreciate criticisms/advises. Thank you very much!

Comment: Putting `continue` at the end of the while loop is useless.

Comment: @RPM edited~ still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I see, I think infinite `while` loop is the problem here.

### PHP and Sockets

If you cannot use NodeJS, try out PHP with Sockets. Should work for this pretty well!

### Improvements

You said you search for improvements. Here they are.
Plus I would use Angular to bind data retrieved from server to the view.

### The view file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        {{ HTML::script('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js') }}
        <style>
            #chat {
                width: 300px;
            }
            #input {
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
            }
            #messages {
                padding-top: 5px;
            }
            #messages > div {
                background: #eee;
                padding: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                border-radius: 4px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chat">
            <input id="input" type="text" name="message" value="">
            <div id="messages">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var $messagesWrapper = $('#messages');

            // Append message to the wrapper,
            // which holds the conversation.
            var appendMessage = function(data) {
                var message = document.createElement('div');
                message.innerHTML = data.body;
                message.dataset.created_at = data.created_at;
                $messagesWrapper.append(message);
            };

            // Load messages from the server.
            // After request is completed, queue
            // another call
            var updateMessages = function() {
                var lastMessage = $messagesWrapper.find('> div:last-child')[0];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '{{ url('chat/refresh') }}',
                    data: {
                        from: ! lastMessage ? '' : lastMessage.dataset.created_at
                    },
                    success: function(messages) {
                        $.each(messages, function() {
                            appendMessage(this);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log('Ooops, something happened!');
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        window.setTimeout(updateMessages, 2000);
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            };

            // Send message to server.
            // Server returns this message and message
            // is appended to the conversation.
            var sendMessage = function(input) {
                if (input.value.trim() === '') { return; }

                input.disabled = true;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '{{ url('/chat') }}',
                    data: { message: input.value },
                    success: function(message) {
                        appendMessage(message);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Ooops, something happened!');
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        input.value = '';
                        input.disabled = false;
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                });
            };

            // Send message to the servet on enter
            $('#input').on('keypress', function(e) {
                // Enter is pressed
                if (e.charCode === 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    sendMessage(this);
                }
            });

            // Start loop which get messages from server.
            updateMessages();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Routes

```
Route::post('chat/refresh', function() {
    $from = Input::get('from', null);

    if (is_null($from)) {
        $messages = Message::take(10);
    } else {
        $messages = Message::where('created_at', '>', $from);
    }

    return $messages->latest()->get();
});

Route::post('chat', function() {
    return Message::create(['body' => Input::get('message')]);
});

Route::get('chat', function() {
    return View::make('chat');
});
```

### Model

```
class Message extends Eloquent
{

    protected $fillable = ['body'];
}
```

I think, code is pretty straighforward... Comments should explain everything.

Comment: Wow...thanks a lot man! This is a great code! I've heard about web sockets too but I'm also targeting users with legacy browsers (IE8, IE7, etc) and I heard those browsers do not support web sockets. 

Also, I would love to use websockets in the first place but its reliance on nodejs library (socket.io) put me off. Please correct me if I'm wrong (most probably), I'm still new to these stuff. 

Again, thank you very much! I appreciate your help. :)

Comment: @Andryco btw, I noticed after I input more than 5 items and refresh the page, on the second POST request after all the msgs are loaded, 2-3 more duplicate of the last 2-3 messages are appended again making a total of 8 messages displayed instead of should be displaying only 5 from the database. Why is this so?

Comment: I have already figured out the reason why and edited your answer. Please check it out and if you accept it or have other ways to workaround the problem, I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, not specifying order might cause that problem. In Laravel, you can use `latest()` scope method, which is shortcut for `orderBy('created_at', 'asc')` (and `oldest()` for opposite order direction). I also split the code to not repeat same methods in `if-else` statement. I would still get only last N (10 in my case) messages on initial load. You can implement "Load earlier conversations" button to get another N older messages ;)